# ArcGIS Python Toolbox Parameter Dependencies

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis, arcmap

I'm trying to connect two parameters. In the first, the user inputs a file which contains a list (each line is one item). In the second, I'm hoping to set a parameter of type Field or GPValueTable. Here's a look at how this part of the code currently looks like:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
        #Define parameter definitions

        # Input Features parameter
        in_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input Features",
            name="in_features",
            datatype="DETextFile",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # User selection
        selection_field = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Selection list",
            name="selection_field",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        
        selection_field.parameterDependencies = [in_features]
        
        # Derived Output Features parameter
        out_features = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Output Features",
            name="out_features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Derived",
            direction="Output")
        
        out_features.parameterDependencies = [in_features.name]

        parameters = [in_features, selection_field]
        
        return parameters
```

The text file looks like this:

```
A
B
C
```

The toolbox dialog output is just A. I'm having a hard time understanding what ArcGIS intended to create here. Perhaps I'm using the wrong data types, but their parameter explanation doesn't make it very clear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are confused with the arcpy terminology, I think. The second parameter's `datatype="Field"` does not imply *data can be read/parsed from a text file* where the data columns are written, in fact it is the schema/fields of a proper table and expectation is not a simple text but [the field objects](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm) of a table/feature class (in the toolbox's run-time, assignment to `arcpy.Parameter` yields a geoprocessing value object but it is a different discussion). If you look at [the "Creating value table parameters" section here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E2BAA5D4440D41D6AAB948922186905A), GPFeatureLayer's (`param0`) fields are populated in `param1` automatically when the dependency is set.

The solution is setting your `selection_field` to GPValueTable and populating the `selection_field.filters[0].list` by reading the `in_features`'s content after the parameter is altered but has not validated in `def updateParameters(...)`. Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370250/updating-valuetable-parameter-of-arcpy-python-toolbox-tool.